# multiple email addresses as notification subscribers to aws elastic beanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

how do I set up notifications for more than one email in elastic beanstalk?

I've tried and got an error.

one email works fine

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

EB email notification is **managed by SNS**. Thus to add extra emails or notifications subscribes, you can add them using SNS console.

If you create your email notification, in **SNS console** there will be automatically created topic with the name `ElasticBeanstalkNotifications-Environment-<your-env>`. Once you open up the topic you will have option to `Create subscription` where you can add new emails, SQS queues, HTTP endpoint, Lambda function and more.